# Qudratic Equations - Promise Problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np-hard, quadratic-programming

Is the follwing promise problem NP-hard?
**Input:** A system of quadratic equations.
**Promise:** The system has either one or zero solutions.
**Question:** Does the system have a solution?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Also, what exactly do you mean by "a system of quadratic equations"?

Comment: I think it's NP-complete, and I know that quadratic programming is NP-complete so I probably need to reduce from this, but I'm stuck here - I don't know which reduction to do...

Comment: Without the promise there's a standard proof that the problem is NP-hard.  Do you know that proof?  I suggest you study it (or try to re-derive it yourself), then try to adjust the reduction to apply to your problem, and edit the question to show your work and what progress you made and at what point you got stuck.  You might also want to learn about Unique k-SAT and Valiant & Vazirani's result on that.